# Golden Arrow Drill Down for A/R Invoice SAP B1

Tags: crystal-reports, sapb1

Upon adding a picture for the golden arrow in the last document number column, I wanted it to link to the A/R invoice of the specified Document number
I created the link however I feel like probably my linking code  to the picture has an issue that's why it's not running correctly.

This is where I inserted the Golden Arrow Image:

[image]

I then added the following codes for linking to the OINV DocNum:

[image]

The following is the error I get in RED:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the DocEntry instead of DocNum as DocEntry is the primary key and they are two different numbers.

```
SELECT Top 3
DocEntry , 
DocNum
FROM 
Oinv
```

results:

| DocEntry | DocNum |
| --- | --- |
| 89170 | 1001000 |
| 106304 | 1001001 |
| 122080 | 1001002 |

[image: DocNum & DocEntry]